# How to allow unauthorized users access some queries/mutations using AppSync with OpenID Connect auth type?

Tags: openid-connect, aws-appsync, unauthorized

I've set up Developer Authenticated Identities for my custom authentication and I retrieve JWT token for users from Cognito and use it as an Authorization header in all requests to AppSync api.
AppSync Authorization type was set to OpenID Connect with Cognito as provider.

The problem here is that I can only access AppSync api when I have JWT token but mutation which returns it is also belongs to the same AppSync api endpoint that was secured by OpenID Connect.
I don't really want to move part of the api to one endpoint and the rest to another.

Is there any way to make some queries/mutations publicly available and others secured by token?
Can I use any directives similar to @aws_auth or define my own directive / custom authorizer?

Comment: Unfortunately, your use case is not currently (Feb '19) supported in AWS AppSync. It's an area we are actively working on so stay tuned for updates.

Answer (score 0):

you can use IAM authentication type. Create identity pool and allow unauthenticated users. Add AWS_IAM as additional auth provider in appsync config.Then you can use @aws_iam annotation next to your public api in schema.